QEMU VM into Boxes
I am a long time linux user (ubuntu-budgie 24.04) trying out VMs recently. I followed this recipe to create a QEMU vm running GhostBSD 24.04.2. It works great from the command line using qemu-system-x86_64. How do I get this vm to show up in gnome-boxes?

I don't know GNOME boxes very well, I find it an program that oversimplifies the underlying problem so far that it misses the point.
Anyways, that the way you're running the VM (simply calling qemu from the command line) of course "registers" that VM nowhere. You would want to define this VM within the bounds of libvirtd, so that virtualization frontends can "see it" (don't know if GNOME boxes then will – but that's what I'd assume).
So, the most straight forward way would be to … keep doing that and ignore the existence of GNOME boxes and libvirtd?
The better thing to do is probably installing virt-manager; in there, make a connection to the "User session", add a new VM inside that context. You can select your existing storage (what was named .img in your recipe), or set up a fresh VM.
If you want to use your current storage, I'd recommend you convert it to a different format, and move it to a better location; what I'd recommend would be that you run before you start setting up the new VM:
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/libvirt/images
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 -f raw ~/.qemu/ghostbsd/ghostbsd.img  ~/.local/share/libvirt/images

if virt-manager asks you to set up a new pool, use ~/.local/share/libvirt/images as location.

After having set up the VM and having verified it runs in virt-manager, you can probably also see it in GNOME Boxes. (Or you use the imho superior virt-manager, whatever you prefer.)

This works, and I see your point about boxes vs virt-manager. Very helpful, thanks.
